# d3.js V4 Button Zoom Implementation acting weird

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement d3 pan and zoom feature. The default pan and zoom works fine, but the requirement is we need zoom in and zoom out buttons as well. I have also implemented zoom button and it works as well. The weird part is when I first move the image and click zoom button the image is moved back to the previous position, not only that when I first zoom with mouse and start zooming again with the button the image scale out to the default and starts zooming again. How do I manage to start zooming from where I transfer from mouse event to button click event.

```js
let imgHeight = 400,
  imgWidth = 900,
  width = 900,
  height = 450;

let zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);

let svg = d3.select("#canvas").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + "px")
  .attr("height", height + "px");

svg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,25)")
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g");

svg.append("image")
  .attr("width", imgWidth + "px")
  .attr("height", imgHeight + "px")
  .attr("href", "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg");

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

let zoomIn = d3.select("#zoom-in");

zoomIn.on("click", function() {
  zoom.scaleBy(svg.transition().duration(750), 1.2);
})
```

```html
<div id='canvas'>
</div>
<div id="tools">
  <button id="zoom-in">
    +
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling zoom on two different "g" elements, you just need to append once, just remove the second append.

```
svg = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,25)")
  .call(zoom)
```

that's why you're experiencing this problem, the zoom function is being applied to nested elements

Comment: So the weird problem was because it was implemented on two g element?

Comment: if you inspect your old example in your browser, you will see that the zoom is being applied to two different nested <g> tags, you binded the manual zoom to the first <g>, then you appended another and the button zoom was being called in that second one